# Encrypted 2013 Access Database Password will not validate on Windows 8 using Classic ASP

Tags: excel, encryption, asp-classic, windows-8, ms-access-2013

Trying to use Classic ASP to access a 2013 Access Database that is encrypted with a password.  I have tried a number of different approaches to rule out the problems.

Here is the ASP page

```
<%@ Language="VBScript"%>
<% Option Explicit %>
<%
Dim objConn
Dim strVersion

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strVersion = objConn.Version

With objConn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.Properties("Data Source") = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test2013.accdb"
.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = "test"
.Open
.Close
End With
%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>ASP Test Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<% Dim TestString %>
<% TestString = "ASP is Working!"%>
<%=TestString%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have successfully run this code with a password encrypted database on Windows 7 computer but I am not able to get it to work on Windows 8.1.  Here are the scenarios that I have tried on Windows 8.1

> **Scenario 1:** Set the DefaultAppPool (Enable 32-Bit Applicaions = False) gives the `ERROR: ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'.  Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.` So I assume I need to have (Enable 32-Bit Applicaions = True)
>
> **Scenario 2:** Set the DefaultAppPool (Enable 32-Bit Applicaions = True) without the database password and the page loads successfully so I know everything is connecting correctly.
>
> **Scenario 3:** Set Access 2013 Database - Encryption Method = Use default encryption (Higher security) with DefaultAppPool (Enable 32-Bit Applicaions = True) gives the `ERROR: Microsoft Office Access Database Engine error '80004005' Cannot open database ''. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.`
>
> **Scenario 4:** Set Access 2013 Database - Encryption Method = Use legacy encryption (good for reverse compatibility and multi-user databases) with DefaultAppPool (Enable 32-Bit Applicaions = True) gives `ERROR: Microsoft Office Access Database Engine error '80040e4d' Not a valid password.`
>
> **Scenario 5:** I also created an Access 2010 encrypted database from a different computer instead of Access 2013 and copied it over to the Windows 8.1 computer.  When running the code, it gave me an `ERROR: Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Unrecognized database format 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.accdb'.`  Not sure what is going on with this but figured I would include it in case it gave anyone an idea of what might be happening.
>
> **Scenario 6:** Opened up Excel and went into the Macros.  I copied the code above directly into the vba editor and manually ran it.  The code ran correctly and did not give any errors.  When I changed the password it gave the appropriate Not a valid password error so the code was functioning.  This makes me believe that this should somehow work using Classic ASP but can't figure out what is causing the problem.

I am looking to keep this running on Classic ASP with the Access Database.  Ideally I want the database to have an encrypted password to prevent others from accessing the database, but if I can't get it to work I may have to leave the database unencrypted. Any advice on how to fix this or what other options to consider?

FOUND A FIX FOR THIS IN CASE ANYONE ELSE COMES ACROSS THIS PROBLEM.

I already installed Access 2013 retail software on the computer but I tried installing the 2013 Access runtime as well.  I downloaded the AccessRuntime_en-us_x86.exe, installed it, rebooted the computer, and now it is working.  Here is the link to the download.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Some reports of problems with Access passwords here http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/